# Ajax call for PHP MultiThreading

Tags: php, ajax, multithreading, pthreads

One of my JavaScript ajax call the following php file -

```
-----------------------MyAjax.php-----------------------------

function myMethod($userName)
{
 echo $userName;
}

class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
 public function __construct($userName) {
    $this->userName = $userName;
 }

 public function run() {
    myMethod($this->userName);
}
}

$stack = array();
$stack[0] = new AsyncOperation("ifti");
$stack[1] = new AsyncOperation("jami");

foreach ( $stack as $t ) {
   $t->start();
 }
```

I'm not getting the response string from the ajax response. It may be due the the thread operation.
Is there any way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: You could avoid to use Threads if the output is generated from them. :)

Comment: I can't avoid it. Because the processing is a bit complex and I need to use it for other purpose too.

Comment: You could try to split the ajax call in two or more and to handle them results separately (in different php files). Not knowing what you are trying to do, it's not simple for me to find a solution.